# Even though I installed jest-transformer-svg in the Next.js14 and jest environment, a Cannot find module error appears

Tags: testing, svg, next.js, jestjs

I am currently writing jest code in the next.js 14 environment.

I keep getting an error saying the svg file can't be found,
jest-transformer-svg
Even though I installed and set up the library, the same error continues to occur.

What's the problem?

If I comment out the current svg file and run npm test again, it works normally.

- jest.config.js

```js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({ dir: './' });

const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.svg$': 'jest-transformer-svg',
  },
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

[image]

- public/images/svgs/index.ts

```js
import WhiteBannerLogoImage from './WhiteBanner.svg';
import DarkBannerLogoImage from './DarkBanner.svg';
import DarkLoginModalBannerImage from './DarkLoginModalImage.svg';
import WhiteLoginModalBannerImage from './WhiteLoginModalImage.svg';
import WhiteLoadingSpinnerImage from './WhiteLoadingSpinner.svg';
import DarkLoadingSpinnerImage from './DarkLoadingSpinner.svg';

export {
  WhiteBannerLogoImage,
  DarkBannerLogoImage,
  DarkLoginModalBannerImage,
  WhiteLoginModalBannerImage,
  WhiteLoadingSpinnerImage,
  DarkLoadingSpinnerImage,
};
```